# Loop through child images of a parent for a Nivo Slider

Tags: images, loop, php

I want to use a [Nivo slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/) to cycle through the children of a parent page one by one, how can I do that?

I have the following piece of code that grabs **ALL** the children of a parent page and displays them:

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => $post->ID));
foreach($pages as $post)
{
setup_postdata($post);
$fields = get_fields(); ?>
    <?php echo $fields->title; ?>
<?php } wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Is there a way to show 1 child image and upon clicking the next arrow on the Nivo it shows the next child image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get attached (i.e. child) images of a post, try using [`get_children()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children). e.g.:

```
<?php
$child_image_args = array(
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_parent' => $postID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment'
);

$child_images = get_children( $child_image_args );
?>
```

Which returns an associative array of child images. Then, just loop through them, e.g. using [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image), to output. e.g.:

```
<div id="nivoslider">
    <?php
    foreach ( $child_images as $child_image ) {
        wp_get_attachment_image( $child_image->ID );
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Nivo Slider integration is mostly out of scope for WPSE, but if you want to advance manually, change the `manualAdvance` setting to `manual` in your `#nivoslider` jQuery instantiation.