# How to create a simple slideshow out of a post image gallery?

Tags: images, gallery, slideshow

Are there any solutions to transform a default image gallery into a simple slideshow as seen in [this theme](http://portfolium.wpshower.com/portfolio/sollicitudin-un)?

Note: click to move to the next picture in the gallery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use any slider jquery plugin you wish, but to feed the slideshow you need the photos.

Galleries in WordPress are composed of posts with post_type attachment, and attachments that are attached to a post have that posts ID as their post_parent. So to get the images for the slideshow or slider, you need to find posts, that are of post_type attachment, and are children of the current post.

This article has more information on attachments:

http://digwp.com/2009/08/awesome-image-attachment-recipes-for-wordpress/

If you browse to the bottom of the article there is code to grab all the attachments attached to the current post:

```
$args = array(
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => null,
    'numberposts'    => -1,
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        echo apply_filters('the_title', $attachment->post_title);
        echo wp_get_attachment_link($attachment->ID, 'thumbnail', false, false);
    }
}
```

This can be used as a basis for generating the markup for the slideshow/slider by modifying the html in the post loop.

This question deals with using nivoslider and image attachments:

[Loop through child images of a parent for a Nivo Slider](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39211/loop-through-child-images-of-a-parent-for-a-nivo-slider)

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be a good solution. Do you know how to remove the featured image from those attachments? Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Grab the ID of the featured image ( it's stored int he post meta `_thumbnail_id`) and if `$attachment->ID` is equal to that ID, do not process that attachment and move on to the next